# How to develop and test an iOS framework in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I have followed a tutorial on [iOS-Framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework). On the last part "*Developing the Framework as a Dependent Project*", I have created the framework project and a test project which includes the framework.

However, when I try to open at the same time both projects in XCode, I am getting :

```
Cannot open "MyLib.xcodeproj" because it is already open in another workspace.
```

How can I develop my framework and test it every 30 seconds like all the developers do?

I am using `XCode 4.6.2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to create an XCode workspace:

1. Choose File > New > New Workspace.
2. Enter the workspace name, and specify its location in your file system.
3. Click Save.
4. In the project navigator, Control-click in the empty space below the list.
5. Choose Add Files to “YourWorkspace”.
6. Navigate into the folder containing the project package.
7. Select the framework project xcodeproj and click Add.
8. Redo the steps 4 to 7 for the test project

I found the workspace documentation in the [XCode User Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/020-Start_a_Project/start_project.html).